# League of Legends issue

Tags: crash, playonlinux

I've been trying to play League of Legends on Ubuntu, but it crashes before the client shows up. I'm using PlayOnLinux. I tried their forum, but it seems dead. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: One Ubuntu user said they had to install DirectX 9 and Internet Explorer 8 first: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=33303&iTestingId=94347 (be sure that you install them in the same virtual drive as LoL)

Comment: Sorry to ask im very new. But how to i install these programs

Comment: I'm not on my Ubuntu computer right now, but I believe there are installers built into PlayOnLinux. Look for "install components" or something in your PlayOnLinux virtual drive's configuration

Answer (score 1):

As the comment said, you need Directx 9 (I'm not sure you need Internet Explorer 8, but you can also try that). I am assuming you are using LoL 6.x.

To install, do the following:

- Open PlayOnLinux
- Open COnfiguration window
- Select Install components
- Select Directx9 to install

Now it should work.

As an aside, have you tried WineHQ? In my opinion is better than PlayOnLinux and there is much more documentation available. 
Full information [here](https://www.winehq.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the info how do i check which version of league im using i installed directx9 and now it just disappears before the patcher appears no bug splat

Comment: After reading trough the winehq it seems the play on linux script outdated. But how to i intall it with wine alone

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to use some of the wine version listed which contains some text like "League_of_legends". I got LOL working normally on Kubuntu 14.04 using Wine 1.7.19_LeagueOfLegends2. Check this video: [League Of Legends on Kubuntu, Ubuntu, Xubuntu 14.04](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwitrtzu1PXNAhVHJR4KHfFHBjUQtwIIHTAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DuCB4UWQXU4Y&usg=AFQjCNFULTpFpkw7U4gIR4XNIFdR_uEEog&sig2=adeoZCyYYyAPVYOxol_O4w) This worked for me perfectly. You must override the `dnsapi.dll` library on wine configuration.

Some components that worked for me:

- dx9
- IE8
- IE6
- Adobe Air

To install League Of Legends in stand alone form:

The best way to do this, is install LOL on a virtual Machine using Windows XP or Windows 7. After installation, DO NOT upgrade LOL. Just copy the installation folder from your virtual machine, and paste it inside the PlayOnLinux Vitual Drivers folder, into the default, or another prefix made by playonlinux. For example. On playonlinux, create a new virtual disk named "League_of_legends", install the desired components on this disk like, IE8, Adobe Air, etc. Paste the installation folder of LOL into the folder of this virtual disk. In the Miscellaneous tab on playonlinux configuration of your virtual disk, click on Run .exe on this virtual disk. Browse for the LOLLauncher.exe. The game should open the patcher, and start the update. I have done this process like 3 times, and always works for me.
Hope this helps. Best regards.

Comment: How do i override the dnsapi.dl also whenever i try  to install ie8 its says theres a newer version installed on your pc and cancels the install

Comment: To override the library, go to Settings, select your virtual drive(where LOL is installed under PlayOnLinux virtual drives), go to wine configuration, Click on Libraries Tab. In the "New override for library" text field, type: `dnsapi`  then, click Add and then Apply. Accept the canches pressing OK.  In the Applications Tab, be sure to select Windows XP or Windows 7. Test different settings. In this link, there is information about installing LOL, is the official PlayOnLinux documentation: [LOL on PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-1135-League_Of_Legends.html)

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can just install [lutris](https://lutris.net) and add it to your Lutris Cloud Account it will work out of box (tested Ubuntu 18.04 + Compiz + nvidia-390)